# how to get tomcat host and port number in load balancing?

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, load-balancing

I have successfully configured my `java` project with `load balancing` with `HTTP server` two `tomcat`.

Now I need to know which tomcat serves my request ?

For that , I need to get the tomcat host and port number and displaying it in the `jsp` .

This is what I have tried,

```
<%= "Server Name : "+ request.getServerName()+ " Port : "+ request.getServerPort()%>
```

But I got the `HTTP server` **port** and **host** only.

How can I show the host and port particular tomcat serve my request ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the server details using the following API

```
 InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
 InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```